# Need help compressing .txt files and not losing data whilst compressing them

Tags: python, python-3.x, gzip, compression

I'm trying to compress my .txt file which are being made within another code but every time I compress them they go into a `winrar` file and lose all the data within them so all the text goes.

This is the code I'm using:

```
import gzip
with gzip.open('dictionary.txt.gz', 'wb') as f:
    f.write
```

I don't see anything wrong with it as it is actually working but like I said the `winrar` file (compressed file) loses all its data and I'm very confused as to why. This isn't even the hard bit to what I have to do `:(`

Comment: `f.write` doesn't do anything

Comment: `f.write(data)` to write things into the file

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to gzip an existing file, the Python documentation gives a good [example of how it can be done](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html?highlight=gzip#examples-of-usage).

For your file, it would look something like this:

```
import gzip
import shutil

with open('dictionary.txt', 'rb') as f_input, gzip.open('dictionary.txt.gz', 'wb') as f_output:
    shutil.copyfileobj(f_input, f_output)
```

The [shutil.copyfileobj](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/gzip.html?highlight=gzip#examples-of-usage) function allows you to copy one file like object to another one. This saves you have to read the contents in, and then write them out.

Comment: Excellent I'm glad it helped. Don't forget to click on the grey tick under the up/down arrows to accept the answer as the accepted solution.